# How to implode an associative array with keys

Tags: php, arrays, implode

i have array like this

```
array(
[0] => array(
   'name' => 'bob',
   'age' => 23,
 ),
 [1] => array(
   'name' => 'elly',
   'age' => 24,
 ),
 [2] => array(
   'name' => 'susan',
   'age' => 15,
 ),
);
```

how can i get string like "bob, elly, susan". is there a php function for doing this?

Comment: You can make a temp array with only the needed values and then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

something like this

    <?
 $first_array = array(
   [0] => array(
     'name' => 'bob',
     'age' => 23,
   ),
   [1] => array(
     'name' => 'elly',
     'age' => 24,
   ),
   [2] => array(
     'name' => 'susan',
     'age' => 15,
   ),
 );

 $temp_array = array();

 foreach($first_array as $value) {
  $temp_array[] = $value['name'];
 }

 $output = implode(", ", $temp_array);
    ?>

Comment: you can do it like this  $res =array_column($your_array, "name");
echo implode(",", $res);